# Number of nonisomoprhic planar graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

How many nonisomoprhic planar graphs (V, E) are there with |V| = 6
and |E| = 10 assuming that each vertex has degree ≥ 3?

Comment: I would begin by observing that the sum of the degrees of the vertices is $20$, so only two degree sequences are possible. Then try to find the non-isomorphic planar graphs for each of those degree sequences.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on Brian M. Scott's hint, the possible degree sequences are $4,4,3,3,3,3$ or $5,3,3,3,3,3$. The second sequence is easy to handle, since there is a full vertex (connected to all). On removing this vertex (and associated edges), we have a graph on $5$ vertices with each degree $2$. This is only possible for $C_5$ and hence the original graph is $W_6$ (wheel on $6$ vertices), which is planar.

Similarly for the other sequence also it is easy. As a hint if the two degree $4$ vertices are not adjacent, they have to be adjacent to all degree $3$ vertices (this gives just one graph), else if the two degree $4$ vertices are adjacent, their neighbours have either two or three common degree $3$ vertices. Now I hope you can figure out the rest.

Your final answer is $3$.

Comment: There is certainly also a planar graph with sequence (4,4,3,3,3,3) where each of the two degree-4 vertices is connected to all the degree-3 vertices (but not to the other degree-4 vertex).

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Sorry my mistake. Updated the answer.